# svn update file from outside location

Tags: svn, version-control

I have checked out a folder using svn and trying to commit in.
But it is showing svn: Illegal repository URL. I tried few options to fix this, but it didnt help.I m able to view status , log etc., and able to access the URL but unable to check it in.

Now I m going to freshly checkout using root user and tryint to checkin. 
Now the question:
can I just overwrite those files modified by me taking it from earlier folder(where checkin failed) If not what can be best possible solution ?

(note:I m keeping track of who is changing what and i wont face any issue related to merging.)

Thanks!
Kmr

Comment: Do a fresh checkout (don't use root!) and copy/paste the full console input/output of what you did and what's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is perfectly fine to overwrite the modified files from your old folder to your new checkout folder, just make sure that if there were any commits between your old checkout and your new one you merge those changes into your modified files.

Answer (score 0):

If your checkin has failed then it has not been committed to svn repository. You can always try to take out a fresh repository with `svn co` and do `svn ci file1 file2 ..` again.

How ever, you must debug, why did you get in the state where it is telling you illegal repository url. The only possibility, I see is that the working repository was corrupted and has lost the target url.

Next time do an `svn info` to see the details of the repository.